# Poor text display in rgl output with dark background

Tags: r, opengl, rgl, htmlwidgets

When I output an `rgl` scene using OpenGL that includes text and a dark background, the text does not display properly.

Sample code:

```
library(rgl); library(htmlwidgets)
open3d()
bg3d(color = "black")
text3d(0, 0, 0, text = "Text", color = "blue")
saveWidget(rglwidget(), "Example.html")
```

Output in R's default device:

[image: Default]

Output from HTML widget (displayed here in Google Chrome):

[image: HTML]

What can I do to correct for this behavior?

Comment: I wonder if it might be intentional since typical annotations are black and need a whitish halo in order to remain visible on a dark background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set to `black` the `background` option of `saveWidget`.

```
library(rgl); library(htmlwidgets)
open3d()
bg3d(color = "black")
text3d(0, 0, 0, text = "Text", color = "blue", specular="black",)
saveWidget(rglwidget(), "Example.html", background = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: The same problem occurs in ShinyRGL, but this solution will not work. Any idea how to fix it?

Lets say in ui.R I'm calling plot:
rglwidgetOutput("myPlot")

Comment: @Art Your problem is interesting. I suggest you to open a post on SO and ask for a solution.